# How to get/enable Salesforce Lightning Experience for a Developer Org?

Tags: lightning-experience

I am looking to explore the new Salesforce Lightning Experience but was wondering on how to get it for a Developer Org. In my existing Dev Org, I don't seem to find it at all. Do we need to raise a case or is there any other process associated with to get it enabled or configured?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to a [blog](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2015/08/future-of-crm-salesforce-lightning.html) on the salesforce website:

> Lightning will become instantly available October 17th with the
>   release of Winter ‘16

Although, according to the lightning experience [FAQ](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Experience_FAQ), there is a pilot program where you can [request pre-release access](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/lightning-ee-signup.jsp).

Answer (score 1):

There are basically three essentials steps you need to follow

1. Take advantage of world-class training with [Trailhead](http://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/modules)
2. Request a [pre-release](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/lightning-ee-signup.jsp)
3. Register for lightning sessions at [Dreamforce](http://www.salesforce.com/dreamforce/DF15/)

Answer (score 0):

Many people reported that its not working for existing developer org. Need to register a new org after registering follow these steps.

```
     - a.   Click Setup | Create | Packages and then click Edit. 
       b.   Click Continue. 
       c.   Type a namespace and then click Check Availability to see if it’s unique.
       d.   Click Review My Selections and then Save
       e.   From Setup, click Develop | Lightning Components.
       f.   Select the Enable Lightning Components checkbox and click Save.
```

I followed this doc which worked for me.

Also you can follow this document https://developer.salesforce.com/resource/pdfs/Lightning_QuickStart.pdf

Comment: That looks like Lightning Experience on the cover, but the content is all about Lightning Components and Lightning Apps. Were you able to get the Lightning Experience set up by creating a new dev org?

Comment: @martin I just created a new developer org and I can see the "Lightning App Builder" is available in developer section. Here is a tutorial on lightning app builder. https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lightning_app_builder/lightning_app_builder_intro

Comment: Salesforce has gone a bit overboard with their "Lightning" branding, but I believe the Lightning Experience refers to the new desktop ui.

Comment: @SarojBera Lightning Experience is different from Lightning Components, while the later is available for the users to use, however, the former one is yet to be out and is made available upon request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe that the original poster was referring to the new SalesForce User Interface.

With this being said you need to first complete the following TrailHead module, https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/trail/lex_admin_migration . This entire Trail should only take you about 3hrs and 25mins depending on your learning style.
Once you have completed that you can then request a PreRelease here, http://bit.ly/lightningcomponents .

I also highly suggest checking out everything you can regarding it at DreamForce when you have some downtime away from the #AwesomeAdmin and #DynamicDev related learning.

I personally also joined the * Release Readiness & Feature Adoption * Group in Success.

Answer (score 0):

In setup,search for lightning experience hyperlink,once u click on that link you will find a button to enable lightning experience
The link below will help u [enter link description here](https://salesforceglobe4u.blogspot.com/2016/07/how-to-switch-from-salesforce-classic.html)